# clang eager to inline at cost of stack

Tags: c, kernel, clang

Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)

Rewording with example as far too many people got fixated on "recursive" when it was about stack usage, and the one recursive example was the lowest fruit (fix that, and you win more!)

The project has recently moved to mark all functions "static" that are not prototyped in headers, and only used in the specific source file.
llvm appears to be quite eager to inline functions, which is often desirable, especially in userland.

However, in kernel, there is a fixed stack of 16KB. Sometimes, the inlining does the wrong thing.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
// clang -O2 -g -Wframe-larger-than=1 -o stack stack.c 
#define current_stack_pointer ({                   \
        register unsigned long esp asm("esp"); \
        asm("" : "=r"(esp)); \
        esp; \
                })

__attribute__((noinline))
static void lower(unsigned long top)
{
        uint64_t usage[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                usage[i] = usage[i] + 1;

        printf("%s; stack now %lu : deepest - we care about this one\n",
                __func__, top - current_stack_pointer);
}

// Changing this one to be inlined or not. It is only called once
// on the way down the stack, it's not "part" of the deep stack, and
// it is undesirable that its "cost" is pushed on the deep stack when
// inlined.
//__attribute__((noinline))
__attribute__((always_inline))
static void step_one(unsigned long top)
{
        uint64_t usage[200];

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
                usage[i] = usage[i] + 1;

        printf("%s; stack now %lu\n", __func__, top - current_stack_pointer);
}

__attribute__((noinline))
static void start(unsigned long top)
{
        uint64_t usage[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                usage[i] = usage[i] + 1;

        printf("%s; stack now %lu\n", __func__, top - current_stack_pointer);
        step_one(top);

        lower(top);
        printf("%s; stack now %lu\n", __func__, top - current_stack_pointer);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        uint64_t usage[100];
        unsigned long top;
        top = current_stack_pointer;

        printf("%s; stack now %lu\n", __func__, top - current_stack_pointer);

        // Make it use stack space, ignore this, just to set some variables
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                usage[i] = usage[i] + 1;

        start(top);

}
```

So here we go, force `step_one()` to be **noinline**:

```
stack.c:55:5: warning: stack frame size of 824 bytes in function 'main'
stack.c:41:13: warning: stack frame size of 856 bytes in function 'start'
stack.c:30:13: warning: stack frame size of 1624 bytes in function 'step_one'
stack.c:13:13: warning: stack frame size of 824 bytes in function 'lower'
# ./stack
main; stack now 0
start; stack now 864
step_one; stack now 2496
lower; stack now 1696 : deepest - we care about this one
```

That is great, even though we called `step_one` on the way down, and the stack grew to handle it, it is released and `lower` is not affected.

Hurrah.

Now, changing `step_one` to be **inlined**

```
stack.c:55:5: warning: stack frame size of 824 bytes in function 'main'
stack.c:41:13: warning: stack frame size of 2440 bytes in function 'start'
stack.c:13:13: warning: stack frame size of 824 bytes in function 'lower'

# ./stack
main; stack now 0
start; stack now 2448
step_one; stack now 2448
lower; stack now 3280 : deepest - we care about this one
```

Here we are, `step_one` was inlined, and its cost is now part of `start` and as we descend into `lower` that cost is still taking stack space.

Hurroo.

This is unfortunate. For kernel files, inlining functions can make it worse (with stacksize in mind) and it at times it has gone from a frame-size of "88" to "1800". due to inlining.

I suspect it has already been answered, there is no way to tell clang to prefer a lean stack over inlining benefits.

Comment: do not have recursion in the kernel - that is the best sollution.

Comment: I knew at least one person would go there. But not an option at the moment, so ignoring..

Comment: Are you sure that 540 bytes are to be multiplied by 11? If the function is inlined, it might be the total. Did you look into the generated assembly?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre] so other people can explore and test. Include the compiler switches you are currently building with.

Comment: Updated to include example. Dropped mentioning "recursing" as it distracted.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any way to ask clang to limit stack usage as a compile option for some source files?

I don't know of any, and wouldn't expect it to exist (now or in the future).

What you're hoping for only makes sense in the presence of recursion (without recursion, "reduce stack size" means "always inline to reduce stack space wasted by function epilogue/prologue"). Currently (as I understand it); clang doesn't even know if a function is recursive and just has a "max. cutoff depth for caller contexts" approach.

> Manually figuring out what to "noline" is time-consuming (for the human)...

It would be annoying and possibly error prone; but shouldn't be time-consuming (given that recursion is rare, even when developers have no reason to care about stack size).

The problem with putting `__attribute__(noinline)` on the log function is that it will be applied to all callers and prevent the log function from being inlined when it is beneficial. What you'd really want is the reverse - e.g. some kind of (hypothetical) `__attribute__(noinline_callees)` you can put on the recursive function. That behavior could be achieved by putting the recursive function in its own separate file/compilation unit; but that will probably end up being even more annoying.

Answer (score 0):

So far the best option we have come across is to use `-finline-hint-functions` for the kernel compile, then it will only inline functions that we ask it to. Changing the default away from try-to-inline-everything, and we have a chance to keep the stack small.